# Hex Value for request.Timeout in C#

Tags: c#, .net, hex, reflector

I decompiled a DLL using reflector. The retrieved code put Hex values in all assigments for request.Timeout. Something like this:

request.Timeout = 0x401640;

It compiles fine, but I dont know if leaving those values like that will make the app behave the same when running. I could change them to DEC but the thing is there are so so so many of them and its not practical.

Im using .net 3.5.

My question is: Will it behave the same as if DEC values were set?
Thank you.

Comment: In Reflector, go to Tools -> Options.  Select the Number Format: Decimal and click ok.  Then close and reopen Reflector (that saves the change to the config).  Next time you disassemble code it will show the decimal.

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer: Yes

Long Answer: Yes, but you should change them to decimal integers any way. Programming is about getting the software to run correctly, but it's also about readability.

Whoever gets to read that code in the future (you included), will be an easier time.

Comment: It would be safer to add comments with the decimal representations of the numbers, if those are really needed.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Perhaps, but the day will come when the value will be changed, but the comment will not. Code should be clear enough to need the least amount of comments possible. Having a comment on a value feels silly and yet potentially misleading/dangerous. My 2 cents

Comment: Changing that many values to decimal representations is almost certainly guaranteed to introduce bugs that would not have otherwise occurred, simply due to typing or pasting errors.  If comments are that objectionable, my vote would be for converting them to decimals on a case by case basis, if and when that is actually needed.

Comment: I would just change Reflector to show the decimals and decompile again to avoid the hex altogether.